# How can I check to see if a string exists in any ActiveRecord in a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, full-text-search

Would this require full-text search or is it possible to do with a method?

I have a table of Chinese sentences and I want to find all the records that include a string.

For example:

```
irb(main):007:0> Hint.all
  Hint Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "hints".* FROM "hints" 
[
    [0] #<Hint:0x007fb99c9d1900> {
                :id => 107,
          :sentence => "你叫什么名字？",
              :user => nil,
           :learned => nil,
        :created_at => Sat, 05 Jan 2013 21:04:06 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Sat, 05 Jan 2013 21:04:06 UTC +00:00
    },
    [1] #<Hint:0x007fb99f2acc30> {
                :id => 108,
          :sentence => "当时有约翰做他们的助手。",
              :user => nil,
           :learned => nil,
        :created_at => Sat, 05 Jan 2013 21:04:23 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Sat, 05 Jan 2013 21:04:23 UTC +00:00
    },
    [2] #<Hint:0x007fb99f2ac618> {
                :id => 109,
          :sentence => "马可和家人可能过着舒适的生活，因为他们在城里有自己的房子，家里有仆人。",
              :user => nil,
           :learned => nil,
        :created_at => Sat, 05 Jan 2013 21:19:43 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Sat, 05 Jan 2013 21:19:43 UTC +00:00
    }
]
```

I want to search for "名字" and it return a list of records that have that string in the `sentence` table. In this case it would find a match in [0].

(if full-text search is required, can you recommend something that will work with Chinese and heroku, as close to free as possible?)

Comment: I don't see how it couldn't require a full-text search unless you create another mechanism for mapping characters (and sequences/words) to records. You might want to consider something like Solr, although I've not used it for Chinese.

Comment: I tried texticle, bu it didn't work for Chinese. It errored: ```NOTICE:  text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do something like this or am I missing something about unicode symbols?

```
Hint.where("sentence LIKE '%名字%'")
```